# Use same collections.Counter for more classes

Tags: python, counter

I have 2 classes and I count different stuff with them. I would like to use the same collections.Counter object for the two classes, because some of the things I count are in common. What is the most pythonic way to do this?

So far I have 2 different classes using 2 separate counters:

```
from collections import Counter


class Shapes():
    def __init__():
        self.c = Counter(rotate=0, translate=0, operation=0)


class Tools():
    def __init__:
        self.c = Counter(hammer=0, scissor=0, operation=0)
```

One option would be to move the counter outside all classes, but it doesn't look so nice because it's not needed to have it global, I want to share it only between two classes.

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(rotate=0, translate=0, hammer=0)


class Shape():
    pass


class Tool():
    pass
```

What I would like to do is something like this, with just one counter for both classes:

```
A = Operations()
B = Tools()
# Counter['operation'] = 0 at this point

A.do_operation() # Do something and increase c['operation'] by one
B.do_operation() # Do something and increase c['operation'] by one

# Now Counter['operation'] = 2
```

Comment: Have a parent class with a class member that does the counting?

Comment: Do rotate, translate, hammer and scissors have to be part of the counter? If not, you could take them out into another object and only have the counter count. Then you could pass in the same counter into both Shapes and Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a class that maintains a Counter then subclass that as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

class BaseCounter:
    counter = Counter()
    def update(self, value):
        self.counter.update(value)

class Shape(BaseCounter):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

class Tool(BaseCounter):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

shape = Shape()
shape.update("abc")
tool = Tool()
tool.update("xyz")

# at this point, referencing either tool or shape would equivalent
for kv in tool.counter.items():
    print(*kv)
```

**Output:**

```
a 1
b 1
c 1
x 1
y 1
z 1
```

You could also use a singleton pattern like this:

```
from collections import Counter

class SingletonCounter(Counter):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(SingletonCounter, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance


class Shape():
    def __init__(self):
        self._counter = SingletonCounter()
    @property
    def counter(self):
        return self._counter


class Tool():
    def __init__(self):
        self._counter = SingletonCounter()
    @property
    def counter(self):
        return self._counter
```

Comment: I like it, would it also work to make BaseCounter a singleton and then declare an instance of BaseCounter inside the class Shape and Tool in their __init__()? I'm not sure if it's really an advantage, but with this I would avoid using inheritance where the child classes don't really have a logical connection to the parent BaseCounter.

Comment: @Tripola Yes - you could use a singleton. I'll enhance the answer

Comment: Consider [whether you *really* need a singleton](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202204/singleton_is_a_bad_idea.html).

Comment: @chepner I added the singleton approach only in response to another comment. I do not necessarily condone the practice

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to create the `Counter` instance outside the classes and add it as an attribute of the `Shape` and `Tool` classes:

```py
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(rotate=0, translate=0, hammer=0)


class Shape:
    def __init__(self, counter):
        self.c = counter


class Tool:
    def __init__(self, counter):
        self.c = counter
```

To avoid repeating the `__init__` methods, you might create a MixIn with the `__init__`:

```py
class CounterMixIn:
    def __init__(self, counter):
        self.c = counter

class Shape(CounterMixIn):
    ...

class Tool(CounterMixIn):
    ...
```

What you choose depends on what interface you need/want: do you want the counter to be an internal detail? Choose **CtrlZ**'s solution.
Do you want to be explicit about the counter? You could choose something in line with what I suggested.